# How to access account details of EKCalendar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, calendar, account

Can you guys tell me what is that private Method to get Account Information of Calendar in iPhone. I have tried with accountName but couldn't get any success.

Answer (score 3):

```
accountName
```

is private property ,
there's a way only to parse the description you will get from

```
-[EKCalendar description]
```